# I'am using primeng datatable to display some data, i want to to combine 2 columns to single <p-column> field?

Tags: angular, primeng

```
export class Model
{
    public name:string;
    public phone_number:string;
    public profession:string;
    public address:string;
    public district:string;
    public membership:string;
}

    this is my model class data format.     

<p-column field="name" header="Name"></p-column>
<p-column field="phone_number" header="Phone Number"></p-column>
<p-column field="profession" header="Profession"></p-column>
<p-column field="address" header="Address"></p-column>
```

this is how i'am displaying data but the issue is how can combine both address and district column of model class to single  field?

Comment: Use templating so you have more control over cell content.

Comment: but how to use templating inside datatable?

Answer (score 2):

With a template it can be done like this :

```
<p-column field="address" header="Address - (District)">
   <template let-col let-user="rowData" pTemplate="body">
       <span>
           {{user['address'] - (user['district'])}}
       </span>
   </template>
</p-column>
```

Comment: You could also add a function to just format the string for you and call it within the {{ interpolation }}